# tensorflow-probability: AttributeError: Tensor.op is meaningless when eager execution is enabled

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-probability

I want to build a classification model that returns a distribution over probabilities for each class. I.e., instead of getting a single probability that a class is positive, getting a distribution of this probability, that would provide a sense of the uncertainty of the model on assigning this probability of being positive to a certain instance.

So say that we want to classify a patient as having cancer.  Rather than getting a single number back as the probability of this event, e.g., 0.8 I would like to get a distribution of probabilities from which I could calculate the mean, being 0.8 but also the standard deviation or the quantiles of the probability of the patient having cancer.  As I said the objective is to provide a measure of the certainty or uncertainty of the model on its prediction which otherwise would be a single number (probability) 0.8.  Like asking: "OK you believe that given the data the probability that the patient has cancer is 0.8 but how certain you are that the probability is indeed 0.8 and not say 0.6 or 0.4?"

To implement this idea I am using tensorflow-probability in the following manner.  Possibly the same idea can be implemented in a better way with tensorflow-probability in which case please propose.

In any case, my implementation results in an exception.  I am interested in explanations of the exception and any proposals for a better way to implement the basic idea.  The code is the following:

````
x_in = Input(shape = (n_features, ))

x = Dense(10, activation = 'relu')(x)  # Dense imported from tensorflow.keras

x = Dense(10, activation = 'relu')(x)

x = Dropout(0.5)(x)  

x = Dense(tfpl.IndependentNormal.params_size(1))(x)  # Up to now the layers were deterministic.  Now I create a tensor that contains the parameters of a Normal distribution

x = tfpl.IndependentNormal(1)(x)  # This layer samples from the Normal Distribution that is defined by the parameters passed to it from the previous layer , i.e. , loc and scale

y_out = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(x) # This layer converts the continuous value sampled from the IndependentNormal to a probability.


model = Model(x_in, y_out)


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-73-3328bd28ff8e> in <module>
     16 
     17 
---> 18 model = Model(x_in, y_out)

~\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    240       # Functional model
    241       from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import functional  # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
--> 242       return functional.Functional(*args, **kwargs)
    243     else:
    244       return super(Model, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

~\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\base.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    455     self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    456     try:
--> 457       result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    458     finally:
    459       self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

~\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\functional.py in __init__(self, inputs, outputs, name, trainable)
    113     #     'arguments during initialization. Got an unexpected argument:')
    114     super(Functional, self).__init__(name=name, trainable=trainable)
--> 115     self._init_graph_network(inputs, outputs)
    116 
    117   @trackable.no_automatic_dependency_tracking

~\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\base.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    455     self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    456     try:
--> 457       result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    458     finally:
    459       self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

~\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\functional.py in _init_graph_network(self, inputs, outputs)
    140 
    141     if any(not hasattr(tensor, '_keras_history') for tensor in self.outputs):
--> 142       base_layer_utils.create_keras_history(self._nested_outputs)
    143 
    144     self._validate_graph_inputs_and_outputs()

~\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer_utils.py in create_keras_history(tensors)
    189       the raw Tensorflow operations.
    190   """
--> 191   _, created_layers = _create_keras_history_helper(tensors, set(), [])
    192   return created_layers
    193 

~\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer_utils.py in _create_keras_history_helper(tensors, processed_ops, created_layers)
    224                        'op wrapping. Please wrap these ops in a Lambda layer: '
    225                        '\n\n```\n{example}\n```\n'.format(example=example))
--> 226     op = tensor.op  # The Op that created this Tensor.
    227     if op not in processed_ops:
    228       # Recursively set `_keras_history`.

~\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in op(self)
   1213   def op(self):
   1214     raise AttributeError(
-> 1215         "Tensor.op is meaningless when eager execution is enabled.")
   1216 
   1217   @property

AttributeError: Tensor.op is meaningless when eager execution is enabled.
````